# How to avoid conflict in VR military training route?

Tags: military, airspace

I'm new pilot. I know there is 1 mile distance from cloud above 10000 ft. Because plane can fly as fast as they want.

However I noticed that like `VR1203`, they're military training route where more than 250 knots are permited below 1500 ft under VFR. So how do we avoid conflict? What is my flight plan need to fly across such route?

Comment: VR routes have an upper altitude limit that is easily reachable by GA aircraft.  Look up what that is and just fly over the top of it.  (1500ish?)

Comment: VR routes that have altitudes above 1500 ft are identified by 3 number digits, such as VR 207.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap3_section_5.html), paragraph 3-5-2., is a good source of information with respect to Military Training Routes (MTR). I would advise that you become thoroughly familiar with this paragraph and its sub-paragraphs.

Importantly, with respect the altitude of MTR (VR/IR) routes, paragraph 3-5-2 d. 1.,  states: *(Emphasis is mine)*

> **Military training routes will be identified and charted as follows:**

> **1. Route Identification.**
>
> > (a) MTRs with no segment above 1,500 feet AGL must be identified by **four number characters**; e.g., **IR**1206, **VR**1207.
>
> > (b) MTRs that include one or more segments **above 1,500 feet AGL** must be identified by **three number characters**; e.g., **IR**206, **VR**207.
>
> > (c) Alternate IR/VR routes or route segments are identified by using the basic/principal route designation followed by a letter suffix, e.g., IR008A, VR1007B, etc.
>
> **2. Route charting.**  . . .

Also, in particular to your specific question, AIM paragraph 3-5-2 g. states: *(Emphasis is mine)*

> Nonparticipating aircraft are not prohibited from flying within an MTR; however, extreme vigilance should be exercised when conducting flight through or near these routes. **Pilots, while inflight, should contact the FSS within 100 NM of a particular MTR to obtain current information or route usage in their vicinity. Information available includes times of scheduled activity, altitudes in use on each route segment, and actual route width.** Route width varies for each MTR and can extend several miles on either side of the charted MTR centerline. Route width information for IFR Military Training Route (IR) and VFR Military Training Route (VR) MTRs is also available in the FLIP AP/1B along with additional MTR (slow routes/air refueling routes) information. When requesting MTR information, pilots should give the FSS their position, route of flight, and destination in order to reduce frequency congestion and permit the FSS specialist to identify the MTR which could be a factor.

Here is some additional information on IR and VR MTRs from the FAA's [Aeronautical Chart User's Guide, page 19](https://aeronav.faa.gov/user_guide/20230615/cug-complete.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Very clear. So I need to contact FSS